# Rails, Product model containing one or more Part item model references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Concerning a Product model that houses multiple Part items;

...for example;

```
Product (Car)
 Part (Engine) x1
 part (Wheel) x4
 part (Chassis) x1
```

---

I'm trying to wrap my head around setting this up and some help would be appreciated. In my Product model I'm assuming I set up an:

```
has_many :parts
```

When I do this though I can only assign one part to each product and I can't specify a numerical value? How would you approach this problem?

Comment: Taking the time to read this will save you lots of time and frustration. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I appreciate that, but when you're already frustrated and scratching your head a nudge in the right direction can be a hell of a thing.

Comment: It can be a bit daunting but reading through that really does help :P

Comment: I've come to the conclusion I need to use a has_many through association based on that guide. Is there any good tutorials that go into this a bit deeper as that's only surface level overview. I'm able to add parts with a quantity column, and I can return the parts back from a manifest using @product.parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a many to many assocation between Product and Part you need a join table:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_parts
  has_many :parts, through: :product_parts
end

class Part < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_parts
  has_many :products, through: :product_parts
end

class ProductPart < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :part
end
```

Here `product_parts` serves as the join table. You could for example attach four wheels to a car by:

```
car = Product.create(name: 'Car')
wheel = Part.create(name: 'Wheel')
4.times { car.parts << wheel }
car.parts.count # => 4
car.parts
# => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Part id: 1, name: "Wheel", created_at: "2018-12-06 15:12:18", updated_at: "2018-12-06 15:12:18">, #<Part id: 1, name: "Wheel", created_at: "2018-12-06 15:12:18", updated_at: "2018-12-06 15:12:18">, #<Part id: 1, name: "Wheel", created_at: "2018-12-06 15:12:18", updated_at: "2018-12-06 15:12:18">, #<Part id: 1, name: "Wheel", created_at: "2018-12-06 15:12:18", updated_at: "2018-12-06 15:12:18">]>
```

This would create 4 rows in the `product_parts` table. Another way to solve this would be by adding a quantity column to the `product_parts` table.

```
car.product_parts.create(part: wheel, quantity: 4)
```

Adding "metadata" to the join model is only possible when its created explicitly. Note that this won't actually alter the count and length of the association like in the previous example.

```
car.parts.count # => 1 
car.parts
# => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Part id: 1, name: "Wheel", created_at: "2018-12-06 15:12:18", updated_at: "2018-12-06 15:12:18">]>
```

Rather you have to use the join table records to get the quantity:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @product.product_parts.each do |pp| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= pp.part.name %></td>
      <td><%= pp.quanty %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, a car has many parts and a part belongs to one car. This can be setup as follows:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :parts
end

class Part < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :car
end
```

This assumes that the Part model has a column called car_id, which is used to specify which car the part belongs to. You'll then be able to do:

```
car.parts
part.car
```

EDIT:

Say we have 5 parts:

```
part1 = Part.find(1)
part2 = Part.find(2)
part3 = Part.find(3)
part4 = Part.find(4)
part5 = Part.find(5)
```

And one product:

```
product1 = Product.find(1)
```

If I want to assign the parts to belong to the product, I would do:

```
part1.product_id = product1.id
part1.save
```

I can do that to all 5 parts, which will assign them all to the parent product.

If you want to see which parts belong to the product, you can do:

```
product1.parts
```

which will return

```
[part1, part2, part3, part4, part5]
```

As well as

```
part1.product
```

Which will return product1

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, which part didn't I answer?

Comment: If you have 5 parts and want to assign them to the same product (which has an ID of say 4), then simply assign all 5 parts a 'product_id' attribute of 5

Comment: So, to clarify; the distinction between a product and a part isn't clear. You could sell a car part for example (an engine Part) on its own or as part of an assembly (Product) say. If I understand your suggestion correctly this can't take that into account or am I wrong? Apologies if I am.

Comment: A part has a product ID and a product doesn't. A part is assigned to a product (which product it belongs to) through the product_id it is assigned. I'm not sure what you're trying to do that you're stuck with

Comment: I'm going to give this a go later tonight, my issue looking at it though is that if I wanted to assign parts I've assigned to one car, I'd have to keep recreating new copies of said parts. My idea was to have an inventory of parts that I could assign to products and the quantities of, as a way of determining stock/inventory etc needed. Appreciate the clarification though.